# OmegaConf - Merging multiple files with name as key

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, omegaconf

### Question

I am experimenting with the `OmegaConf` library and am having trouble with the `OmegaConf.merge` method. Referring to the project structure, there are two configuration files. When using the `OmegaConf.merge` method, it combines both the configurations into one as expected. However, this leaves me confused as I have a hard time determining which configurations belong to a specific configuration file.

The reason why I wish to merge the configurations is because I would like to have a single global variable with all the configurations to use across modules.

*I do not wish to use the `Hydra` library due to limitations faced previously.*

### Project Structure

```
project_root
├── config
│   ├── example1.yaml
│   └── example2.yaml
└── src
    └── main.py
```

### Code

**config/example1.yaml**

```yaml
file: foods.txt
check: --A--

sample: XXA1
```

**config/example2.yaml**

```yaml
items:
  - XXA1
  - XXA66
  
users:
  - user1
  - user2
```

**src/main.py**

```py
import omegaconf
from omegaconf import OmegaConf

CONFIG = None  # Configurations stored here which will be imported across multiple modules.

example1_config = OmegaConf.load('../config/example1.yaml')
example2_config = OmegaConf.load('../config/example2.yaml')

CONFIG = OmegaConf.merge(example1_config, example2_config )

print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(merged_configs))
```

### Current Output

```yaml
file: foods.txt
check: --A--
sample: XXA1
items:
- XXA1
- XXA66
users:
- user1
- user2
```

### Desired Output

```yaml
example1:
  file: foods.txt
  check: --A--
  sample: XXA1
example2:
  items:
  - XXA1
  - XXA66
  users:
  - user1
  - user2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OmegaConf.merge` combines the keys of its inputs, much like python's builtin `dict.update` method.

To get your desired output, you'll need to add a level of nesting to your inputs:

```py
CONFIG = OmegaConf.merge(
    {"example1": example1_config},
    {"example2": example2_config},
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried it and works exactly like expected.